# Switch tabs on TabController on Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a question on Windows.Forms.TabController.

My tab controller has 3 pages. How do I move to a new tab page once in every 4 seconds? 
ie, 0th - 4th second - stay on tab1,
 5th to 8th second - move to tab2, 
9th to 12th sec - on tab3, 
13th to 16th - on tab1 and so on.

Comment: [Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) are your friend.

Comment: I am sorry if the question is unclear.

Comment: timer and after 4 seconds `tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0-2;`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4):

use a timer. Place the first 2 lines in class before constuctor

```
 int currentTab = 0;
 System.Windows.Forms.Timer dispatcherTimer;
```

Place the below 3 lines in constructor

```
 dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
 dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
 dispatcherTimer.Interval = 4000;
 dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

Place this somewhere in the class

```
 private static void OnTimedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    tabControl.SelectedIndex = currentTab++;
    if(currentTab==3)
       currentTab = 0;
 }
```

Comment: Why are you using a `System.Timers.Timer` instead of a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`? if you don't assign the Synchronizing Object of the timer to `this` you will get a cross thread operation error.

Comment: Thanks for the quick knowledge about Timers. I am a newbie to C# development and hence the question. Apologies for the basic doubt.

Comment: @user2276269 no need to apologize, we have all been there at one time or another.

Comment: Yes  Ehsan, I am trying to fix the Cross Thread Operation error now

Comment: @user2276269 You would be better off using the System.Windows.Forms.Timer, it is designed to interface with the UI, if you want to use what Ehsan has posted, put this in your constructor.  `tmr.SynchronizingObject = this;`

Comment: @user2276269 check now, i have updated my code.

Comment: @EhsanUllah You are using a Wpf Timer now, he has a WinForms application. Just add the SynchronizingObject to your previous code or change it to a System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Comment: @MarkHall ahhh i mis read your comment.